# Why 'delete' doesn't check a property for garbage collector?

Tags: javascript

After run a code like that:

```
var index = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
     for(var i = 1000; i--;){
          var key = "key" + index++;

          window[key] = index;

          delete window[key]
     }
}, 100)
```

I see in timeline (google developer tools) that the memory increases lots of memory in few seconds and when I force GC (GC button in timeline) it doesn't decreases.

If this property can't be accessed from window and doesn't have other references to it, why GC doesn't clean it?

Comment: The GC hasnt run yet. Consider the overhead to constantly ensure the gargbage is collected

Comment: Looks like you're missing a semicolon on the delete statement as well.

Comment: Considering that you are using an interval that adds and immediately removes 1000 entries, I would expect memory to remain constant with or without GC.

Comment: @RyanS Exactly. The GC isn't going to run between your assignment and deletion lines. Most likely, it's allocated then deleted on the spot which is why you don't see any change in memory.

Comment: @RyanS I click on the GC button and the memory doesn't decreases.

Comment: @JonathanM But I'm seeing a change. The memory growls a lot in few seconds.

Comment: @MuriloKunze, that's new information. Please add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Moving my comment to an answer, and adding info from other comments:

Your loop adds and then immediately removed the reference, in a compiled language this might even be skipped completely. In your case it happens so fast you wont see any change in memory.

Additionally garbage collection is not a constant process. Typically a GC will only run when more memory is required. This keeps the overhead compacted and avoids running the GC when it wont be necessary (the program might end before you reach mem limits, so why bother collecting before it ends)

**EDIT** The memory you see consumed may be due to the interval you setup. Try similar examples without the interval ie. just a loop which uses a new locally declared array

Comment: He revised the question with additional info.

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice idea, but I think GC should clean this memory too.

Comment: Im sure you have your reasons for thinking that, but GC is a topic that has been studied and tested quite extensively so I think you would be better off using it as intended.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you're running `setInterval` at a 100ms delay, it essentially is treated as a continuous function call i.e. there's no time in between to run anything else.

With your test, you should expect to see a gradual increase in memory then a stark drop in memory. Open a New Tab page in Chrome and try running the following then start recording:

```
function allocateOnAnimationFrame() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        window['_key' + i] = i;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(allocateOnAnimationFrame);
}
```

You should see your memory gradually increasing, with some variance, over the next few seconds. After that, you should see something like this:

[image: Wavering memory then a drop off]

Why did we all of a sudden release some memory? If you look closely you'll see that between animation frames, the engine was finally given some time to run the GC.

[image: GC running during animation frame]

**TL;DR**: Your loop is too fast. Slow it down.

Comment: But in my case the memory don't decrease even if I use a clearInterval(interval) and click on the GC button to force it. in few seconds the memory goes to 200MB and never decrease.

Comment: @MuriloKunze You're right. Interestingly, it appears to be a real memory leak issue when dealing with the `index` reference. Try running your code where `index` is replaced with `i` and you'll see what I mean. The memory actually allocates and deallocates as you would expect.

Comment: Nice catch. So we can conclude that delete "mark" the reference to be clean by GC and the problem is with 'index'.

Comment: @RyanS How can multiple intervals be trying to increment it when only one interval is set?

Comment: Ah, I see now that I misunderstood how it functioned. I assumed it was async calls, so if one interval hadnt finished before the next one was due to start, they would have overlapped. I see that this is incorrect and only one interval function will run at a time

Comment: If I take a heap snapshot in 'Profile', it shows me that the most memory is used in array like window["key132165"], but I don't understand it very well.